# How to make if String doesn't ends with in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I had my own idea but it didn't work

```
String.text != String.text.toString().lastOrNull() in arrayOf('+', '-', '/', '*', '.')
```

With error

> operator "!=' cannot be applied to 'CharSequence!' 'and Boolean'

Full:

```
if(operation && currentOpperand.text != currentOpperand.text.toString().lastOrNull() arrayOf('+', '-', '/', '*', '.')
```

(I want to make if `Boolean` "operation" == `true` and string doesn't ends with this array of chars print "+". (making calculator))

Comment: you can use endsWith() in Kotlin

Comment: @ShaluTD I don't think that works because he / she wants to check for an array of characters. endsWith() doesn't accept an vararg of characters. Chaning != with !.equals() should do the work?

Comment: I know about  endsWith(), but i want to make an array and make doesn'tEndsWith, something like this if possible

Comment: `!in` - do you need this? `someString.lastOrNull() !in arrayOf('+', '-', '/', '*', '.')`

Comment: changing != wuth !.equals() didn't worked

Comment: IR42 !in worked! Thank you too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
if (operation && currentOpperand.text.lastOrNull() !in arrayOf('+', '-', '/', '*', '.')){

}
```

or

```
if (operation && arrayOf('+', '-', '/', '*', '.').all { c -> !currentOpperand.text.endsWith(c) }){

}
```

or with `regex`:

```
if (operation && currentOpperand.text.matches(Regex(".*[^+-/*.]\$"))){
    
}
```

Comment: !in worked well, didn't expect such an easy solution :D Madloba